In SVN is it possible to hide the proxy password?
On a shared server, to access an external SVN, it is necessary to go through a proxy. I have configured it in ./subversion/server, and it works correctly. However, I don't like that the proxy password (http-proxy-password) is in plain text. Is it possible to configure SVN so that it asks for the proxy password each time it is executed or that it is not stored in plain text?
On the server, there are multiple users, each with their own proxy credentials.
